# Setting page attributes of every page in a generated ConTeXt file

Tags: context, lua

I'm trying to inject page metadata into a PDF generated with ConTeXt so that the pages have their tabbing order set to use the document structure (for accessibility checks).

Currently, I can inject the metadata but only on the current page of the document.

```
\startluacode 
    lpdf.addtopageattributes("Tabs", lpdf.constant("S")) 
\stopluacode
```

This sets the tab order of one page, however, I can't seem to find a way to loop through every page in the document and re-run the code for each one. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have certain stuff happen on every page you can use the `\beforeeverypage` and `\aftereverypage` hooks (or maybe `\everyshipout`?)

```
\appendtoks
    \startluacode 
        lpdf.addtopageattributes("Tabs", lpdf.constant("S")) 
    \stopluacode
\to \beforeeverypage % or \aftereverypage (try it out)
```

It might be possible to do this in a LuaTeX callback as well, I'll have a look.